# How to add custom background colour in native ads

Tags: android, background-color

Hello i want to implement a native ad in my app what i want is i can implement my custom colour  but i dont know how

here is the line where the colur is to be added

```
NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor(background_color).build();
```

this is the colour i want to implement it is in the color.xml in the values folder

```
<color name="Card_Elevation_Color">#2c2c2c</color>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.Card_Elevation_Color));
        
NativeTemplateStyle styles = new NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor(colorDrawable).build();
```